# Padding expands the size of a <textarea>

Tags: html, css

So, i have a `padding-top` to define some space between the `<textarea>` and the borders of the table.

I need to add a small margin between the `<textarea>` and the table borders. When i don't add the `padding-top` the `<textarea>` goes slightly up, like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTEXS.png

As you can see, the `<textarea>` is slightly above the position of the content of the other rows.

When i add `padding-top:10px;` in my CSS file, the `<textarea>` expands, instead of doing what i pretend, like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVEBd.png

I need the `<textarea>` to be centered like the textboxes in the other table rows.

Here is my html code:

```
echo "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[]' id='checkbox[]' value='".$ppid_reg."' /></td>
<td><input type='text' class='datepicker' name='ppdata[]' value='$ppdata' placeholder='dd-mm-aaaa'></td>";
echo "<td><input type='text' name='ppemp[]' value='$ppemp'></td>";
echo "<td><textarea rows='1' cols='20' name='ppdesc[]' form='form'>$ppdesc</textarea>";
```

(nevermind the variables and the echo's)

I removed and changed the number of rows and cols of the textarea, but the results were the same.

CSS:

```
th, td {padding:0px 10px 10px; text-align:center; }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to put space ABOVE the textarea you have to use margin

```
textarea {margin: 10px 0 0;}
```

If you are using a table and want to center the textarea vertically, you can you vertical-align

```
th, td{vertical-align: middle;}
```

Keep in mind that you need a table-cell for vertical-align to work

Comment: THank you :) Used the textarea margin, and it is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

`text-align` is only concerned with horizontal alignment.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the float left to the input and textarea. Then u can adjust the line-height to make their height same.

**HTML**

```
<table>
   <tr>
       <td><input type="text" /></td>
       <td><input type="text" /></td>
       <td><textarea rows='1' cols='20'></textarea></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table{border:1px solid;border-collapse:collapse;}
td{padding:5px;border:1px solid;}
textarea{resize:none;padding:0 5px;line-height:32px;float:left;border:1px #ddd    solid;height:30px;}
input{padding:0 5px;line-height:30px;float:left;border:1px #ddd solid;height:30px;}
```

Fiddle link is below

http://jsfiddle.net/murli2308/wye2s/2/